# mail not sending using mail()

Tags: php, email

I am attempting to send mail using mail() function. But it does not send the mail. Returns value false.

```
if ( filter_var($_POST['msgEmail'] , FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
{
    $to="pnoushid@gmail.com";
    $from = $_POST['msgEmail'];
    $name = $_POST['msgName'];
    $subject="comments from ".$name;
    $message=$_POST['txtcomments'];
    $message=wordwrap($message,70,"<br>");
    $message=str_replace("\n.","\n..",$message);
    $headers='From: '.$from;
    $mail=mail($to, $subject, $message);
    if ($mail==TRUE)
        $message="<script type='text/javascript'    
                    alert('comment has been sent');
                    </script>";

    else
        $message= "<script type='text/javascript'>
                alert('Comments are not send at this time!.thanks');
            </script>";
}
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: not problem solving but you can just use `if ($mail)` instead fo `if ($mail==TRUE)`

Comment: sendmail_path valid?

Comment: @Pepo_rasta same difference. `if ($mail)` is the same as `if ($mail==TRUE)`

Comment: add `"\r\n"` to all header lines.

Comment: and make a simple test if sendmail is working at all. `mail('pnoushid@gmail.com', 'blaw', 'blaw');`

Comment: of course its same(at least same result), im talking about possibility not necessarity, why write something long, when you can do it simplier? also, im not sure if `if($var == TRUE)` not making one extra comparsion

Comment: im trying to `mail('pnoushid@gmail.com', 'blaw', 'blaw');` but same result.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe installing Sendmail it will work.